# Radiated signal from loft antenna?

Tags: antenna, signal

I have the following home setup in the UK:

[image]

The antenna is used for receiving free-to-air TV transmissions.

I just want to know if it's possible for the signal from the HDMI to DVB-T box to radiate out of the antenna for others in the street to pick up? This is something I obviously want to avoid.

If so, is there any way to block the signal so it's effecitvely an RX only antenna?

The gear used is all Labgear (labgear.co.uk) branded except for the antenna which is SLx and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There is a built in circuit/block diagram tool builtin to the question dialog box

Comment: Unfortunately that feature doesnt seem to work on a phone. I also tried looking for the actual schematics of the devices but the manufacturer doesn't give much info.

Answer (score 2):

You ask "I just want to know if it's possible for the signal from the HDMI to DVB-T box to radiate out of the antenna for others in the street to pick up?"

Yes, that could happen.  The RF out of the HDMI to DVB-T converter will couple through the splitter, with some loss, back through the coax up to the output of the mast mounted amp.  At the amp, things get a little bit trickier to figure out what happens.

At the amplifier in an ideal world, that signal would be totally blocked. However all real world devices have some output to input transfer of power, or leakage.  The question is how much is that leakage.

That (reverse) leakage is characterized by the S12 parameter for the amp. The S12 parameter measure how much signal from the output port (port 2) shows up on the input port (port 1), as a function of frequency.

Any signal that makes its way back to the input of the masthead amp would then be radiated by the antenna. How well that occurs depends of the frequency of the signal and the frequency band for which the antenna is designed.